# Missing AST Classes in Global Transform

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am writing a transform to add some extra annotations to fields that already have a specific annotation.

I have the following configuration that I provide to the compiler

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.PackageScope
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.FieldNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.AbstractASTTransformation
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation

@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CONVERSION)
class InjectorTransform extends AbstractASTTransformation {
  @Override void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {
    source.AST.classes*.fields.flatten().each {
      def field = it as FieldNode
      def found = field.annotations.find { it.classNode.name == 'javax.inject.Inject' }

      if (found) {
        field.addAnnotation(new AnnotationNode(ClassHelper.make(PackageScope)))
      }
    }
  }
}

withConfig(configuration) {
  ast(CompileStatic)
  ast(new InjectorTransform())
}
```

I provide this to gradle using `groovyOptions.configurationScript`

The transform runs as expected but `source.AST.classes` only returns a single class. This class always the first alphabetical class of all the classes that are being compiled. For example if I have classes Bar and Foo, it will return Bar. If I create another class called Alpha, Alpha will be returned.

My question is what could be causing the transform to not be getting all of the classes? Is there an issue with adding a global transform this way, or something that could be preventing the rest of the classes for being visible?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the `inline` method instead of creating a class inside of config script. I'm not sure why the original method didn't work and maybe it's a bug but here the solution.

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.PackageScope
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.FieldNode

import static org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase.CONVERSION

withConfig(configuration) {
  ast(CompileStatic)
  inline(phase: CONVERSION) { source, context, classNode ->
    source.AST.classes*.fields.flatten().each {
      def field = it as FieldNode
      def found = field.annotations.find { it.classNode.name == 'Inject' }

      if (found) {
        field.addAnnotation(new AnnotationNode(ClassHelper.make(PackageScope)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```